# How do I query a many-to-many database in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship linked via an associative table.

The idea is to search one or many ingredients to return one or many recipes, without returning multiples of the same recipe.

**Recipe_Table**
Recipe_ID
Recipe_Name

**Ingredients_Table**
Ingredients_Table
Ingredient_ID
Ingredient_Name

**Associative_Table**
Ingredient_ID (FK)
Recipe_ID (FK)

The query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT r.recipe_name, i.ingredient_name, ri.amount FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri on r.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id 
INNER JOIN ingredients i on ri.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id 
WHERE i.ingredient_name IN ('eggs', 'flour');
```

This works okay but returns multiples of the same recipe, for example, if I query 'eggs' and 'flour' it returns Pancakes twice whereas I only want it to match once.

[Picture of the associative table linking each ingredient_id to a recipe_id and each recipe_id to ingredient_ids with a unique amount for each combination..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztkXn.png)

Comment: Post sample data and expected result. While doing that you might understand that you don't want any other result as you already got.

Comment: It seems reasonable to return the recipe once for each ingredient. What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  **group by Recipe_ID**  in the last of your query.

Comment: I'm afraid that OP will happily accept this wrong answer and come back later to SO asking for help to debug that code.

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you mean , but if response is false u can edit it.

Comment: There is nothing to edit. There is no correct answer to a question that doesn't make sense as it is. What is the meaning of `ri.amount` if you don't know the ingredient it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Well, many to many may be divided into two 1-to-manys each direction.

Like, **1** Recipe has **N** Ingerdients. Or **this 1** Ingerdient is used in **that many** Recipes.

Now, that depends on which direction you're going to go now: are you trying to determine in which Recipes the particular Ingredients are used? 
Or are you intending to select records that yields list of Ingredients by Recipe?

Knowing that, you'd be able group/distinct/aggregate properly.

So what you're up to?

Comment: Yes I am trying to determine in which recipes particular ingredients are used.

Comment: So then you've got your "pancakes" field exposed (at least) twice, and that is 100% natural. You've got ('pancakes', 'flour', '1 lb') and ('pancakes', 'eggs', '2') - that's totally legit, and that's exactly what you've asked.

I don't really get what's confusing you there?